# How to change the selected lines background color

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme

I've created a dark color theme for the text editor in Visual studio pro 2017, however one thing I can't find is how to change is the background color of selected lines in the text. Currently it's black. 
I've seen "display items" under "fonts and colors" that are locked as automatic, as black. I hope its not one of them. Surely there is a way to change it? 
I have not found a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this does the trick for you but you can highlight the current line:

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors

Show settings for: **Text Editor**

Display items: **Highlight Current Line**

Change the color and you got:

[image: Highlighted current line]

Comment: you want multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, all the lines/areas highlighted when you hold left mouse button and drag the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows**: go to **File** > **Settings** > **Editor** > **Color Scheme** > **General** > **Editor** > **Caret row**

Then click on the selector button and choose your color. For example, mine is E6EEF9.

[image]